# How can i add tr inside td with bootstrap-4 table?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to add two rows inside a td like below picture but I can't find any solution of this.
[image: The desired result]

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Row_and_column_spanning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using rowspan attribute in the cell.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can do by using nested table

http://www.corelangs.com/html/tables/table-inside-table.html

Comment: Is this possible with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

You Have Asked (How can i add tr inside td)

To have tr inside td the only way is create another table inside td than you can have tr inside td.

Example :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the image you have added it represent that you want to merge two rows for that you need to use Row Span.

Example for Row Span ( https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the rowspan attribute on td tags in your HTML: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>B/B LC NO Value USD</th>
    <th>ABP Value USD</th>
    <th>Exp N&amp; Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">$ xxxxx<br/>$ -</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$1</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to do this with bootstrap table. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the fiels that you **don't** want to divide into two `rowspan="2"` and then skip the fields that would normally be under them.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Margaret Nguyen</td>
    <td>427311</td>
    <td><time datetime="2010-06-03">June 3, 2010</time></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>533175</td>
    <td><time datetime="2011-01013">January 13, 2011</time></td>
    <td>37.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```